# undo giving user access to a database

Tags: c#, sql, database, ssms

I'm building a web application where one can manage user access of multiple databases. I've used the following code to give a user reading access to a database:

```
    public void giveUserReadRightsForDatabase(int serverID, string dbName, string dbUsername, string myPassword)
    {
        ISFramework.Database myDB = new ISFramework.Database();

        string myQuery = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name ='" + dbUsername + "')" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "BEGIN" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "CREATE LOGIN " + dbUsername + " WITH PASSWORD = '" + myPassword +
 "', CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "END" + Environment.NewLine +

                            "BEGIN TRY" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "USE [" + dbName + "]" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "CREATE USER " + dbUsername + " FOR LOGIN " + dbUsername + Environment.NewLine +
                            "USE [" + dbName + "]" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER " + dbUsername + Environment.NewLine +

                            "END TRY" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "BEGIN CATCH" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "END CATCH";

        myDB.executeNonQuery("DBServer" + serverID, myQuery);
    }
```

and I use the following code to remove the permission:

```
    public void removePermissionsForThisDatabase(int serverID, string dbUsername, string dbName)
    {
        ISFramework.Database myDB = new ISFramework.Database();

        string myQuery = "BEGIN TRY" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "USE [" + dbName + "]" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "CREATE USER " + dbUsername + " FOR LOGIN " + dbUsername + Environment.NewLine +
                            "USE [" + dbName + "]" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "ALTER ROLE db_datareader DROP MEMBER " + dbUsername + Environment.NewLine +
                            "USE [" + dbName + "]" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "ALTER ROLE db_datawriter DROP MEMBER " + dbUsername + Environment.NewLine +
                            "USE [" + dbName + "]" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = N'" + dbUsername + "')" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "DROP USER " + dbUsername + Environment.NewLine +
                            "IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'" + dbUsername + "')" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "DROP LOGIN " + dbUsername + Environment.NewLine +
                            "END TRY" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "BEGIN CATCH" + Environment.NewLine +
                            "END CATCH";

        myDB.executeNonQuery("DBServer" + serverID, myQuery);
    }
```

At the end of the first method, the user can access and read the database, which is good. Though when I do the second method, the user can still access the database, which is not good. I've already debugged and confirmed the program is hitting the methods and executing the queries, so there's gotta be an error in the query itself.

I've tried doing the following line in SQL Server Management Studio itself, which does do its job, so I really have no clue, truth be told. There are never  error messages, but the code doesn't so what it should.

```
 USE [Dev_ISFramework]
 IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = N'Johnny456')
 DROP USER Johnny456
```

Comment: You said *There are never error messages*. this is because you wrapped your query with `BEGIN TRY` and `END CATCH` and the errors getting swallowed

Comment: Ah right. Stupid mistake. I'll try to remove the TRY ... CATCH and see if I get anything.

Comment: @JossefHarush Oh god, removing that stupid TRY CATCH block gave me a decent error. I tried to make a new user, even though there's already one like that. Stupid mistake of copy/paste.

Comment: Glad it helped. please be noted that string concatenation is insecure way for querying your database. *Google* `Sql Injection C#` to learn more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not the expert here, but if your second method uses `BEGIN TRY` at the beginning of your SQL, then attempt to create a user when it exists raises an exception which is silently caught. So your role alternations aren't executed.

You have to revisit whole SQL code used in `removePermissionsForThisDatabase()` to do what you want.